# The complex trigonometric function degenerates to the positive integer

Tags: trigonometric-sums, products

For any integer $N \geq 2$, we have the identity:
$$\frac{\ \prod _{n=1}^{N-1}\ \left(2+2\sum _{m=1}^{n\ }\cos \frac{\ m\pi \ }{N}\ \right)\ }{\prod _{n=1}^{N-1}\ \left(1+2\sum _{m=1}^{n\ }\cos \frac{\ m\pi \ }{N}\ \right)}=N$$

So how to prove it? Any help and suggestion will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you don't know how to prove it, how do you know it's true?

Comment: I believe the identity holds because it comes from a real physical problem about fracture mechanics. And I also verified the identity for N<20 via Mathematica. The left side expression of the equation is neat and orderly, so I wonder if there's some kind of rigorous proof in mathematics.

Comment: For large, $n$, we can approximate the expression as $$A=\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left(1+\frac{1}{(1+\frac{2}{\pi}N\sin(\frac{\pi k}{N}))}\right)$$. And this $A$ can be further simplified as $$\ln(A)=\frac{\pi}{2N}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\pi k}{N})}$$. Which is very very close to $\ln(N)$. Hence, $A≈N$, at least for $N$ sufficiently larger than zero.

Comment: I have verified this identity up to $N=10000$.

Comment: The sum $$\frac{\pi}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\pi k}{N})} ≈\ln(N) +\gamma +\ln\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sin(\alpha)}\right)+\ln(1+\cos(\alpha)) =\ln(N)+B , \gamma \leq B \leq \gamma+ \ln(\frac{\pi}{2})+\ln(2) $$, as $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mescheroni constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following Johann Cigler's [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/a/368807), set $q=e^{\frac{i\pi}{N}}$. We will need the two evaluations
$$\prod_{n=1}^{2N-1}(1-q^n)=\left.\frac{x^{2N}-1}{x-1}\right|_{x=1}=2N \tag{1}$$
$$\prod_{n=1}^{N-1}(1-q^{2n})=\left.\frac{x^{N}-1}{x-1}\right|_{x=1}=N \tag{2}$$
In your expression we can write things in the form
$$2+2\sum _{m=1}^{n\ }\cos \frac{\ m\pi \ }{N}=2+\sum_{m=1}^n(q^m+q^{-m})=\frac{(1-q^{n+1})(1+q^n)}{q^n(1-q)}$$
and
$$1+2\sum _{m=1}^{n\ }\cos \frac{\ m\pi \ }{N}=1+\sum_{m=1}^n(q^m+q^{-m})=\frac{(1-q^{2n+1})}{q^n(1-q)}.$$
Putting everything together, we see that your expression evaluates as
\begin{gather*}
\prod_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{(1-q^{n+1})(1+q^n)}{q^n(1-q)}\cdot \frac{q^n(1-q)}{(1-q^{2n+1})}=\prod_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{(1-q^{n+1})(1+q^n)}{1-q^{2n+1}} \\
=\frac{(1-q^N)}{1-q}\prod_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{(1-q^n)(1+q^n)}{1-q^{2n+1}}=(1-q^N)\frac{\prod_{n=1}^{N-1}(1-q^{2n})^2}{\prod_{n=1}^{2N-1}(1-q^n)}=2\cdot\frac{N^2}{2N}=N
\end{gather*}
as desired.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I rolled back your edit, because the variable in equations (1) and (2) plays a different role from $q$ which is a fixed root of unity. For example, you would say $1,q,q^2$ are the roots of $x^3-1$ rather than those of of $q^3-1$.

Comment: What is $x$ in the first two identities, and what does the evaluation mean? It seems undefined.

Comment: @user2520938: $x$ is a variable, and the notation $P(x)|_{x=a}$ is the evaluation of the polynomial $P$ at $a$.

Comment: The LHS of your identities don't involve an $x$ though, and the RHS is a rational function, not a polynomial, and in fact is a rational function the denominator of which is zero in the point your are evaluating in.

Comment: @user2520938: I should have said that more generally it denotes the limit of the expression, rather than evaluation. In this case, if you cancel the $(x-1)$ from numerator and denominator it coincides with the evaluation of the polynomial that's left at $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's better to present more details about identities 1 and 2 although the conclusions hold.

Comment: @YanChen I suggest working them out as simple exercises, but if anything is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: If $t=q^2$ in equation (2), the monic polynomial $(x^N-1)/(x-1)$ has roots $t, t^2, \dots, t^{N-1}$ hence factors as $(x-t)(x-t^2) \dots...(x-t^{N-1})$. Setting $x=1$, (2) follows.

Answer (score 2):

I have no answer, but it seems that the problem is equivalent with
$\frac{(-1;q)_{N-1}(-q;q)_{N-1}}{\binom{2N-2}{N-1}_q}=N$ for $q=e^{i \pi/N}.$

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment, since it's not an answer?